# Android App files

Tags: android, software-distribution

Here are the files of an Android application.

How can I use them? What software is used to open this project in order to compile an APK executable file?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eclipse . To download it , visit this link [Download Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) after you have to add [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html). When you have installed all, you have to import your project and you could work with them.